# node, session store remove expired sessions

Tags: session, node.js, coffeescript, express

I am trying to implement a session store for an express.js node app
My question are :

1. How do you delete cookie that have a browser session lifetime (marked with expires = false according to connect doc)
2. Should I store session data as a json string or directly as an object

this is the coffee script I came up with so far, using mongoose as I this is the orm I chose for the app

```
    express  = require 'express'
    mongoose = require "mongoose"
    util     = require "util"

    # define session schema
    SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema
      sid     : { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
      data    : { type: String, default: '{}' }
      expires : { type: Date, index: true }

    module.exports =
    class SessionStore extends express.session.Store
      constructor: (options) ->

        console.log "creating new session store"

        options ?= {}

        # refresh interval
        options.interval ?= 60000 

        options.url ?= "mongodb://localhost/session" 

        # create dedicated session connection
        connection = mongoose.createConnection options.url

        # create session model
        @Session = connection.model 'Session', SessionSchema

        # remove expired session every cycles
        removeExpires = => @Session.remove expires: { '$lte': new Date() }

        setInterval removeExpires, options.interval

      get: (sid, fn) ->
        @Session.findOne sid: sid, (err, session) ->
          if session?
            try
              fn null, JSON.parse session.data
            catch err
              fn err
          else
              fn err, session

      set: (sid, data, fn) ->

        doc =
            sid: sid
            data: JSON.stringify data
            expires:  data.cookie.expires 
        try
          @Session.update sid: sid, doc, upsert: true, fn
        catch err
          fn err

      destroy: (sid, fn) ->
        @Session.remove { sid: sid }, fn

      all: (fn) ->
        @Session.find { expires: { '$gte': new Date() } }, [ 'sid' ], (err, sessions) ->
          if sessions?
            fn null, (session.sid for session in sessions)
          else
            fn err

      clear: (fn) -> @Session.drop fn

      length: (fn) -> @Session.count {}, fn
```

Comment: Have you seen [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)? It always grabs the session data from the DB by it's ID and destroys it on the client if needed (`if !expires or Date.now() < expires`), that looks like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty new to node so take this with a grain of salt.

While not directly session oriented the [remember me tutorial on dailyjs](http://dailyjs.com/2011/01/10/node-tutorial-9/) will help a bit I think. Specifically the last bit of code where he verifies login tokens.

Also, I believe it's better to parse the JSON and store as an object. Should be easier to get access to the different cookie bits that way if you take care of the parse up front.